Is there a minimum power required to keep a drone or helicopter in the air - and if so, what is it?
Assuming a mass M and horizontal projection of area A for a hovering object (no wind) like a drone or helicopter, what's the minimum power required to keep it hovering?  Let's assume no ground effects.

Does this answer your question? How much work is done to maintain vertical position (hovering) of a drone?
